# What would be complexity of this recursive algorithm

Tags: time-complexity, code-complexity

How to calculate the complexity of a bit complicated recursive algorithm like this
in this case what would be the complexity of something(0,n)

```
void something(int b, int e) {
     if (b >= e) return;
     int a = 0;
     for(int i=b; i < e; i++)
     a++;
     int k = (b+e)/2;
     something(b, k);
     something(k+1, e);
     }
```

I tried to analyze this algorithm and think it has complexity is n*ln(n) but still can't get a formal proof.

Comment: How so? unless b = e then I can see that.  oh wait nevermind. someone claimed there would be an endless loop but I can only see a possibility of that if b = e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, loop will run for `(e-b)` times and it will call itself **2 times**, but reducing the size of loop by **half**

So, `((e-b)/2)` will run for 2 iteration; once by `(b,(b+e)/2)` and again by `((b+e)/2+1,e)`

Like wise both iterations will again call themself 2 times, but reducing the iteration length by half.

So `((e-b)/4) will run 4 times, and so on.

The height of the recursion tree will be `log(b-e)`, (each node is having 2 children)

So, `time complexity = (b-e) + 2*((b-e)/2) + 4*((b-e)/4) + .....(log(b-e) times)`

this expression evaluates to `(b-e)*log(b-e)`

therefore, time complexity = **O(nlogn)**